Inverse of infinite-dimensional upper triangular matrix
If $A$ is an infinite-dimensional bounded upper triangular matrix in $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$, i.e. $\langle Ae_n, e_m \rangle = 0$ for all $n > m$, where $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is the standard orthonormal basis of $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$, and assuming $\langle Ae_n, e_n \rangle \neq 0$ for all $n$, can we deduce that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$?
If $A$ is a finite-dimensional matrix, the conclusion is obvious. However, if $\langle Ae_n, e_n \rangle = \frac{1}{n}$ and all other entries are zero, it is clear that $0$ is the spectrum of $A$, but not an eigenvalue. I conjecture that $0$ may be the continuous spectrum or the residual spectrum of $A$, but I am unsure of how to show this.

No.
Let $x\in l^2(\mathbb Z)$ be given by $x_n = 2^{-|n|}$.
Let $A$ be given such that for all $n\in \mathbb Z$
$$
\langle A e_n,e_n\rangle=1,
$$
$$
\langle A e_n,e_{n+1}\rangle= - \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}},
$$
all other entries of $A$ set to zero. Since $| \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}|\le 2$, $A$ is linear and continuous on $l^2(\mathbb Z)$.
Then $Ax=0$.

Your example defined an operator on $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, not an operator on $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$.

The same idea works for $l^2(\mathbb Z)$, see edited post.

It is very well known that the point spectrum of the shift operator $S$ defined by $$Se_n=\begin{cases} e_{n+1}& n\le -1\\ 0 & n\ge 0\end{cases}$$ coincides with the open unit disc. Indeed if $|z|<1$ the sequence $v$ $$v_n=\begin{cases}z^{-n} & n\le 0\\ 0&n>0\end{cases}$$is the eigenvector corresponding to $z.$ Thus the point spectrum of $I+2S$ coincides with the open disc centered at $1$ with radius $2.$ Hence $0$ is an eigenvalue of $I+2S.$
